# Using MS SQL ISNULL() with Alias

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two columns (say x and y) and I have a requirement of sorting x, but if x is null then sort by y.

For this very requirement I was using

order by isnull(x, y) asc;

This seems to work with the column name but if I use alias, MS SQL fails to workout the column name and throws out invalid column name exception.

Thus, could anyone please tell me

either how could I use ISNULL with with alias
or if there is any alternative to ISNULL() ??

thanks

Comment: can you post your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE` is the more standard alternative of `ISNULL`.

It can take more than two values compared to `ISNULL` and return's the first non null value from the left.

You cannot refer to aliases inside functions in the ORDER BY

You have two options:

1)  Use column name instead of aliases (which already you have done)

2) Use the `isnull(x,y) as xy` on the select and refer to it in the order by

eg.

```
select a as a-alias, b as b-alias, c as c-alias, x as x alias, y as y-alias, c as c-alias 
,isnull(x-alias, y-alias) xy
from table 
where conditions 
order by xy
```

Comment: select a as a-alias, b as b-alias, c as c-alias, x as x alias, y as y-alias, c as c-alias from table where conditions order by isnull(x-alias, y-alias) asc ----> this query fails and I get an exception invalid column name or similar

Comment: but for the same query if the order by is : order by x-alias asc, y-alias asc -----> this works

Comment: Order by works with column aliases, or original columns but function's require original column names

Comment: Thanks mate, your solution is correct, it works but might not help me as is spits out values from both the cols, however I want to see vals from only first col i.e. x! and do not want to put the cols vals together

Comment: JUST WANTED TO LET YOU KNOW THAT IT WORKED.. THANKS SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

This will not work

```
select Col1 as C1, Col2 as C2
from YourTable
order by isnull(C1, C2)
```

You have to embed you query in a sub query if you want to use the table aliases.

```
select *
from (
      select Col1 as C1, Col2 as C2
      from YourTable
     ) as Y
order by isnull(Y.C1, Y.C2)
```

Or use the column names instead of the aliases.

```
select Col1 as C1, Col2 as C2
from YourTable
order by isnull(Col1, Col2)
```

**Edit:**

If you only want Col1 as output you have these options

```
select Y.C1
from (
      select Col1 as C1, Col2 as C2
      from YourTable
     ) as Y
order by isnull(Y.C1, Y.C2)


select Col1 as C1
from YourTable
order by isnull(Col1, Col2)
```

Comment: At the moment, if I use order by with alias it works perfectly but isnull fails for the same.

Comment: @anonymous - Yes that is what I was trying to explain. You can't use the table alias in an expression, only when used alone. You have to use the original column name if you want to do an expression in `order by`.

Comment: Yep, I understand, thanks for your reply, was a help ! I will try the sub-query but the prob is there are two columns again say x and y but only x is displayed on the web page. col x might have nulls in it and thus the requirement is to sort it by col x but if x is null then sort it with y. In this case 'order by isNull(x, y) asc works fine' and on the web page you would see only col x vals with nulls in it